# Exclude zero from np.linspace in one line

Tags: python, numpy, zero

How can I remove zero from linspace?

this is my list:

```
np.linspace(-3, 3, 1)
--> [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

And I want to achieve this:

```
[x if x != 0 for x in np.linspace(-3, 3, 1)]
--> [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to get your expected result you would need `np.linspace(-3, 3, 7)` to get 7 numbers. Second, your if statement has to be behind the interation in your list comprehension. Working code would be:

```
import numpy as np

print([int(x) for x in np.linspace(-3, 3, 7) if x != 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other way to achieve it without code the loop.

```
import numpy as np

lin_s = list(map(int, np.linspace(-3, 3, 7)))
lin_s.remove(0)
```